# Can we customize the onSave handler in Aviary?

Tags: adobe, cloud, customization, aviary, image-editor

I have tried on the Aviary SDK, is a amazing images editor tools for developer. It really save our time to develop all the function for images edit.

But, one concern about the onSave handler, Aviary will send the edited image to their cloud server, and host it for 72 hours. Therefore, am I right to say we have to make sure our apps has connection with the Adobe cloud? This cloud be a problem if abode cloud service down or Adobe stop the service?

So, anyway to customize the 'onSave' handler for Aviary?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found that if we using the Android SDK, we are able to set the withOutput, which is

withOutput(Uri)
- Sets the output location where the edited image will be saved.

But no idea for web version, for the onSave method.